# Iterate over array with datetimes and select from a dataframe randomly another datetime [with constraints]

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, random

I have a list with biweekly datetimes and a dataframe with Weekly data (below is only part of the list and dataframe). In a loop I need to iterate over the Biweekly list such that:

-For every Biweekly datetime, randomly pick a Weekly date. However, that randomly picked Weekly date must be in the same month as the the Biweekly datetime or 1 month before or 1 month after.

Any suggestions how to do this in a nice and neat way?

**Biweekly**

```
Datetime            
2016-03-1 00:00     
2016-03-15 00:00   
2016-03-29 01:30
```

**Weekly**

```
Datetime            Level1   Level2
2016-03-1 00:00     12       15
2016-03-8 00:00     11       17
2016-03-15 00:00    09       15
2016-03-29 00:00    12       15
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work, assuming you have a list of `datetime` called `biweekly` and a Pandas DataFrame called `weekly`:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def _one_month_before(dt: datetime) -> datetime:
    return (dt.replace(day=1) - timedelta(1)).replace(day=dt.day)


def _one_month_after(dt: datetime) -> datetime:
    new_month = max(1, (dt.month + 1) % 12)
    return dt.replace(month=new_month, year=dt.year + (new_month == 1))


for biweekly_dt in biweekly:
    # First, filter the target dataframe by the desired months:
    lower = _one_month_before(biweekly_dt)
    upper = _one_month_after(biweekly_dt)
    frames_in_range = weekly[(weekly.DateTime >= lower) & (weekly.DateTime <= upper)]

    # frames_in_range holds the weeks to randomly pick from. So:
    result = frames_in_range.sample(1)
```

Alternatively, you could use an external libary to find the surrounding months for you. [relativedelta](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) can do that trick just nicely at the "cost" of a dependency on [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: So I don't have to replace the dt in the code with the name of the dataframe? I get "undefined"  datetime in both def's and "undifined" dt in the for-loop.

Comment: Getting "undefined" as value in that iteration suggests that `biweekly` is not what was assumed in the code above. Are you sure that `biweekly` is indeed a list of `datetime` instances?

Comment: Rather than working with the actual datetime, how can I use the week of the year _dt.weekofyear_ (derived from the datetime) in this code? So, the list should give a list with week [2, 4, ...26]. By iterating over this list, a random week number is sampled from the dataframe (+ and - 3 week numbers arround the corresponding weeknumber)